# echarts - event 3.1.6

Tags: javascript, html, echarts

This is in reference to echars from Baidu (version 3.1.6)

How do I control two charts based on click event on one of them.
In other words - how do I intercept the click event.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 9):

You can use all events listed in the [echarts api documentation](http://echarts.baidu.com/api.html#events). An example of `click` event could be

```
chartOne.on('click', function (params) {
   console.log(params); // do whatever you want with another chart say chartTwo here
   alert( "chartOne clicked" );
});
```

where `chartOne` is an echarts instance. You can use any of the methods listed [here](http://echarts.baidu.com/api.html#echartsInstance) to change second chart/chart-instance from `click`(or any) event on the first(`chartOne`).

Answer (score 4):

> I solved with this:

```
    var myChart = echarts.init(document.getElementById('graph'), 'default');
    function eConsole(param) {
       if (typeof param.seriesIndex != 'undefined') {
            console.log(param);
        }            
    }
    myChart.on('click', eConsole);
    myChart.on('dblclick', eConsole);
```